# Amasty layered navigation show wrong start price in slider

Tags: php, magento, layered-navigation

I have Amasty layered navigation. I shown price filter as slider on my site.
But the problem is price slider range start from different number.

For example, I have products in category with minimum price of 43000 but slider range starts from 68000.

How can I resolve the issue?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Its default amasty module configuration which i did show in layered navigation. Apart from this not done any customization in that module.

Comment: I suggest contacting Amasty or providing some information that could shed some light on the problem you're having.

Comment: I said in comment i did not modify amasty code. Its default amasty module. I just configure it on my project.

Comment: Then the Amasty module is either working properly or it's not, either way there must be a problem with either your project or Amasty's plugin, what are you expecting anyone to be able to tell you without any information on how to reproduce/understand the problem?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the issue. Problem was with super_attribute_price. Magento store min and max price in catalog_product_index_price. At time of reindex it will add min price with configurable product option with minimum value and same for max column for maximum value.

Comment: faced same problem
I remove all Negative price manually. After that layered navigation filter shows the correct range and doesn't show the negative price range . But after running the commands :
sudo php bin/magento setup:upgrade
sudo php bin/magento setup:di:compile
sudo php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
sudo php bin/magento cache:clean
sudo php bin/magento cache:flush

All Negative values reverted and layered navigation show the Negative price range.
Why this happening?

Comment: Products may have some different prices as compared to the indexing table. Please check product prices including configurable and its simple product.